How do I reflect the changes in my UI after a user event given my case (infinite scroll feature)?
I would like a few clarifications on a few features I have in my app.
This is how my components look like now:
Page
├── AnswerForm (client comp)
│
└── AllAnswers (server comp)
    ├── getAnswers - server action (answers)
    ├── display totalAnswers
    └── AllAnswersInfiniteScroll initialAnswers={answers} (client comp)
        └── Votes (client comp)

Because I use the infinite scroll feature, the answers / comments are kept in useState. reavalidatePath() and router.refresh() don't do anything now. Can someone please explain why? I have the same issue with a Votes component too.
If I use AllAnswers (server component) to render the answers, I lose the infinite scroll functionality, but I can use revalidatePath() in my server actions when I add a new answer / comment.
Page
├── AnswerForm (client comp)
│
└── AllAnswers (server comp)
    ├── getAnswers - server action (answers)
    ├── display answers here
    ├── display totalAnswers
    └── Votes (client comp)

How can I update the content on the UI if someone leaves a like or an answer / a comment while keeping the infinite scroll?
Once I'm on "use client" I am in React territory right?
For the Votes component, I also used useOptimistic to make the votes feel faster, but they revert back to their originial values. I guess because the state is not updated?
Here is the link to a question/[id]/page.tsx. At the bottom are the 2 components AnswerForm and AllAnswers.
https://github.com/Andreul369/DevFlow/blob/main/src/app/(root)/question/%5Bid%5D/page.tsx
I think it would be much easier if you look at the components on github instead of the code snippets below.
Also, if you have any suggestions for different improvements, please let me know. Thank you 
AllAnswers (server component):
const AllAnswers = async ({ questionId, userId, totalAnswers, page, filter }: Props) => {
  const { answers, isNext } = await getAnswers({
    questionId,
    page: 1,
    sortBy: filter,
  });

  return (
    <div className='mt-11'>
      <div className='flex items-center justify-between'>
        <h3 className='primary-text-gradient'>{`${totalAnswers} ${totalAnswers === 1 ? 'Answer' : 'Answers'}`}</h3>

        <Filter filters={AnswerFilters} />
      </div>

      <AllAnswersInfiniteScroll
        initialAnswers={answers}
        questionId={questionId}
        userId={userId}
        isNext={isNext}
        filter={filter}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

AllAnswersInifiteScroll (client component):
const AllAnswersInfiniteScroll = ({
  initialAnswers,
  questionId,
  userId,
  filter,
  isNext,
}: Props) => {
  const [allAnswers, setAllAnswers] = useState(initialAnswers);
  const [isNextPage, setIsNextPage] = useState(isNext);

  const pageRef = useRef(1);

  const [ref, inView] = useInView();

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadMoreAnswers = async () => {
      const next = pageRef.current + 1;

      const { answers: newAnswers, isNext } = await getAnswers({
        questionId,
        page: next,
        sortBy: filter,
      });

      if (allAnswers?.length) {
        setAllAnswers((prevAnswers) => [...prevAnswers, ...newAnswers]);
        setIsNextPage(isNext);
        pageRef.current = next;
      }
    };
    if (inView) {
      loadMoreAnswers();
    }
  }, [inView]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const filterAnswers = async () => {
      pageRef.current = 1;

      const { answers: newAnswers, isNext } = await getAnswers({
        questionId,
        page: pageRef.current,
        sortBy: filter,
      });

      setAllAnswers(newAnswers);
      setIsNextPage(isNext);
    };
    filterAnswers();
  }, [filter]);

  return (
    <>
      {allAnswers?.map((answer) => (
        <article key={answer._id} className='light-border border-b py-10'>
          <div className='mb-8 flex flex-col-reverse justify-between gap-5 sm:flex-row sm:items-center sm:gap-2'>
            <Link
              href={`/profile/${answer.author.clerkId}`}
              className='flex flex-1 items-start gap-1 sm:items-center'
            >
              <Image
                src={answer.author.picture}
                alt='profile picture'
                width={18}
                height={18}
                className='rounded-full object-cover max-sm:mt-0.5'
              />
              <div className='flex flex-col sm:flex-row sm:items-center'>
                <p className='body-semibold text-dark300_light700'>
                  {answer.author.name}
                </p>
                <p className='small-regular text-dark400_light500 mt-0.5 line-clamp-1'>
                  <span className='mx-0.5 max-sm:hidden'>•</span>
                  answered {getTimestamp(answer.createdAt)}
                </p>
              </div>
            </Link>

            <div className='flex justify-end'>
              <Votes
                type='Answer'
                itemId={answer._id}
                userId={userId}
                upvotes={answer.upvotes.length}
                hasupVoted={answer.upvotes.includes(userId)}
                downvotes={answer.downvotes.length}
                hasdownVoted={answer.downvotes.includes(userId)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <ParseHTML data={answer.content} />
        </article>
      ))}

      {isNextPage && (
        <div className='mt-11 flex w-full items-center justify-center' ref={ref}>
          <Icons.Spinner className='size-9 animate-spin' />
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

Votes (client compoent):
const Votes = ({
  type,
  itemId,
  userId,
  upvotes,
  hasupVoted,
  downvotes,
  hasdownVoted,
  hasSaved,
}: Props) => {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleSave = async () => {
    await toggleSaveQuestion({
      userId,
      questionId: itemId,
      path: pathname,
    });

    return toast(`Question ${!hasSaved ? 'Saved in' : 'Removed from'} your collection`, {
    });
  };

  const [optimisticUpvotes, addOptimisticUpvote] = useOptimistic(
    { upvotes, hasupVoted },
    // @ts-ignore
    (state, newUpvote) => ({
      upvotes: state.upvotes + newUpvote.upvotes,
      hasupVoted: newUpvote.hasupVoted,
    })
  );

  const [optimisticDownvotes, addOptimisticDownvote] = useOptimistic(
    { downvotes, hasdownVoted },
    // @ts-ignore
    (state, newDownvote) => ({
      upvotes: state.downvotes + newDownvote.downvotes,
      hasupVoted: newDownvote.hasdownVoted,
    })
  );

  const handleVote = async (action: string) => {
    if (!userId) {
      return toast('Please log in', {
        description: 'You must be logged in to perform this action',
      });
    }

    if (action === 'upvote') {
      if (type === 'Question') {
        startTransition(async () => {
          addOptimisticUpvote({ upvotes: hasupVoted ? -1 : 1, hasupVoted: !hasupVoted });
          await upvoteQuestion({
            questionId: JSON.parse(itemId),
            userId,
            hasupVoted,
            hasdownVoted,
            path: pathname,
          });
        });
      } else if (type === 'Answer') {
        startTransition(async () => {
          addOptimisticUpvote({ upvotes: hasupVoted ? -1 : 1, hasupVoted: !hasupVoted });
          await upvoteAnswer({
            answerId: itemId,
            userId,
            hasupVoted,
            hasdownVoted,
            path: pathname,
          });
        });
      }

      return toast.success(`Upvote ${!hasupVoted ? 'Successful' : 'Removed'}`);
    }

    if (action === 'downvote') {
      if (type === 'Question') {
        startTransition(async () => {
          addOptimisticDownvote({
            downvotes: hasdownVoted ? -1 : 1,
            hasdownVoted: !hasdownVoted,
          });
          await downvoteQuestion({
            questionId: JSON.parse(itemId),
            userId,
            hasupVoted,
            hasdownVoted,
            path: pathname,
          });
        });
      } else if (type === 'Answer') {
        startTransition(async () => {
          addOptimisticDownvote({
            downvotes: hasdownVoted ? -1 : 1,
            hasdownVoted: !hasdownVoted,
          });
          await downvoteAnswer({
            answerId: itemId,
            userId,
            hasupVoted,
            hasdownVoted,
            path: pathname,
          });
        });
      }

      return toast.success(`Downvote ${!hasdownVoted ? 'Successful' : 'Removed'}`);
      // variant: !hasupVoted ? 'default' : 'destructive',
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    viewQuestion({
      questionId: itemId,
      userId: userId || undefined,
    });
  }, [itemId, userId, pathname, router]);

  return (
    <div className='flex gap-5'>
      <div className='flex-center gap-2.5'>
        <div className='flex-center gap-1.5'>
          <Icons.ThumbsUp
            className={cn(
              'size-5 stroke-1 text-[#7B8EC8]',
              optimisticUpvotes.hasupVoted && 'fill-[#6DFF8D]'
            )}
            onClick={() => handleVote('upvote')}
          />

          <div className='flex-center background-light700_dark400 min-w-[18px] rounded-sm p-1'>
            <p className='subtle-medium text-dark400_light900'>
              {formatAndDivideNumber(optimisticUpvotes.upvotes)}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className='flex-center gap-1.5'>
          <Icons.ThumbsDown
            className={cn(
              'size-5 stroke-1 text-[#7B8EC8]',
              optimisticDownvotes.hasdownVoted && 'fill-[#FF6D6D]'
            )}
            onClick={() => handleVote('downvote')}
          />

          <div className='flex-center background-light700_dark400 min-w-[18px] rounded-sm p-1'>
            <p className='subtle-medium text-dark400_light900'>
              {formatAndDivideNumber(optimisticDownvotes.downvotes)}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      {type === 'Question' && (
        <Image
          src={hasSaved ? '/assets/icons/star-filled.svg' : '/assets/icons/star-red.svg'}
          width={18}
          height={18}
          alt='star'
          className='cursor-pointer'
          onClick={handleSave}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

P.S: the server actions work fine.
